# How do this query with a local array in mongo?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have the follow local array, i want to search these registers in my db for show more information, i think in two different solutions but a have problems

```
var clients = [
{
    "Document_Type": "CC", 
    "Document": "52879473"}, 
{
    "Document_Type": "CC", 
    "Document": "19294395"}, 
{
    "Document_Type": "CC", 
    "Document": "53080422"}
{
    "Document_Type": "NIT", 
    "Document": "53080422"}
]
```

1. i think in this but is incorrect because i can have registers with the same Document but different Document_Type.

```
db.person.find
({
"Cliente.Document": { $in: clients.map(s => s.Document) },
"Cliente.Document_Type": { $in: clients.map(s => s.Document_Type) }
})
```

2. This solution dont show me anything.

```
clients.forEach( function(register) {
db.person.find({
"Cliente.Document": register.Document,
"Cliente.Document_Type": register.Document_Type
})
} );
```

If someone can help me I would really appreciate it, and sorry for my English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it possible to use the [$or](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/#mongodb-query-op.-or) operator?

```
db.person.find({
  $or : [
           {"Document_Type": "CC", "Document": "52879473"},
           {"Document_Type": "CC", "Document": "19294395"},
           {"Document_Type": "CC", "Document": "53080422"},
           {"Document_Type": "NIT", "Document": "53080422"}
        ]
});
```

You will see that is the same as

```
db.person.find({ $or : clients });
```

I haven't tested it myself.

Comment: You're a genious!
`db.person.find({ $or : clients });`
it works perfectly, thanks!